# Force stop flexslider from before callback

Tags: flexslider

I need to stop a slider under certain circumstances from before callback to prevent it to go to next slide. I tried following codes

```
slider.stop();
```

and

```
$('.myflexslider').flexslider.stop();
```

without having any luck.

Moreover, I've tried following answer but this doesn't work for me as i've used animation property to "slide" value rather than "fade".
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15632699/363867

Could anybody help?

Thanks
Musa

Comment: `slider.stop()` is working for me in the before callback. What issue are you facing?

Comment: It just goes to next slide! could you show any working example something like on jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shikhar/L0k5q4qu/)

Comment: Thanks for code. Actually i dont want to stop the slideshow rather I want to stop manual execution. For example, user now on slide 3, if he/she presses on next button, i wont allow him/her to see next slide. Any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be possible dynamically in the slider callback function. Flexslider navigation depends on two attributes,  `controlNav` and `directionNav`, both of which are true by default. And once flexslider is initialized, its possible to change the initialization parameters as per the default flexslider code. You could either just remove those directional controls or you'll have to remove the flexslider instance everytime your condition is met and then reinitialize using the correct parameters